# Is there a typo in this problem regarding vectors and points?

Tags: vectors

Suppose we have points $A_1,...,A_n$ on a plane or in space. The broken line $A_1A_2...A_n$ is closed iff $\vec{A_1A_2} +\vec{A_2A_3}+...+\vec{A_{n-1}A_n} = 0$

Shouldnt we have to add $\vec{A_nA_1}$ as well??

Comment: Is this the entire problem, or just background info? It could be that you're asked to (dis)prove the equality.

Comment: If you add it  of course it is $0$ and the line is closed *by construction*, so there's nothing to prove. What is is stated is a condition that *ensures* the line is closed

Comment: the statement is the problem

Comment: When asking about whether something is "a typo", you should cite the source of the statement since whether it is a mistake or not can depend on context.  In the limited form you've given us to check, I agree with @Bernard that an additional term as you propose would take away any utility as a *definition* of a closed "broken line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line is closed, then $A_n = A_1$ and so $A_nA_1$ would be zero. So no, there is no typo in that part of the problem.

Comment: On the other hand, if the line is not closed, then the total sum including $A_nA_1$ would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include the vector $A_nA_1$ in the sum, since if the sum as written is zero, it already is a "closed circuit". Condsider three points $A_1,A_2,A_3.$ The fact that their sum is zero means the vector from $A_2$ to $A_3$ is enough to close it up and make it end where it started.